# heroku and django: heroku stop the function before it done

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku

I deployed a Django app on Heroku. I have a function (inside views) in my app that take some time (3m-5m) before it returns.

The problem is that function doesn't return when the app is deployed to Heroku. On my PC it works fine.

Heroku is not giving me useful feedback. There is no 'timeout' or anything in the logs.

Comment: Not entirely sure what Heroku is doing, but if this long-running function is inside a view as you say, that means users will have to wait 3 to 5 minutes for the page to load when they visit your page. That is far too long - (almost) no-one is going to patiently wait anywhere near that length of time. It sounds like a big performance problem with your function - but if you really need to do something that computationally expensive then I'd recommend doing it periodically "in the background" and caching the result in a database that can then be fetched quickly on page load.

Comment: the function result it's depends on users. so i cant do cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three to five minutes is *way* too long for a request to take. [Heroku will kill such requests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout):

> Best practice is to get the response time of your web application to be under 500ms, this will free up the application for more requests and deliver a high quality user experience to your visitors. Occasionally a web request may hang or take an excessive amount of time to process by your application. When this happens the router will terminate the request if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete.

I'm not sure why you aren't seeing timeouts in the logs, but if you truly need that much time to compute something you'll need to do it asynchronously.

There are lots of ways to do that, e.g. you could queue the work and then respond immediately with a "loading" state, then poll the back-end and update the view when the result is ready.

Start by reading [Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) and then decide how you wish to proceed. We can't tell you the "right" way of doing this; it's something you need to decide about your application.